# Phonetic theories of speech production

Tags: phonetics

So far as I understand, earlier accounts of phonetics considered a theory promoted by Helmholtz known as the "vocal resonance account". It wasn't until the mid-40s that the Acoustic Theory of Speech Production became popular.

Helmholtz articulators were argued to be an oversimplification (Dunn, 1950) - but this is still hard for me to understand because I don't really understand what the Acoustic Theory of Speech Production offered that Helmholtz' account lacked.

Can anyone clarify the differences between the two accounts? Do we assume today a version of the Acoustic Theory of Speech Production?

Comment: Beats me.  Certainly the acoustic theory of speech production has resonators.  Maybe this person Dunn is just complaining about which specific resonators Helmholtz proposed.